# How to get count of failed and completed jobs in an array job of SLURM

Tags: slurm, sbatch

I am running multiple array jobs using slurm. For a given array job id, let's say 885881, I want to list the count of failed and completed number of jobs. Something like this:

Input:

```
<some-command> -j 885881
```

Output: Let's say we have 200 jobs in the array.

```
count | status
120   | failed
80    | completed
```

Secondly, it'd be great if I can get the unique list of reasons due to which tasks failed.

Input:

```
`<some-command> -j 885881`
```

Output:

```
count | reason
80    | OUT_OF_MEMORY
40    | TIMED_OUT
```

I believe `sacct` command can be utilized to somehow get these results, but not sure how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a one-liner like this one, you can get both information at the same time

```
$ sacct -n -X -j 885881 -o state%20 | sort | uniq -c
     16            COMPLETED
     99               FAILED
     32        OUT_OF_MEMORY
      1              PENDING
```

The `sacct` command digs into the accounting information. The `-n -X` parameters are used to simplify the output and reduce the number of unnecessary lines, and the `-o` parameter requests only the STATE column to be displayed. Then the output is fed into the `sort` and `uniq` commands which do the counting.

If you really need two separate commands, you can adapt the above one-liner easily. And you can make it a script or a Bash function for ease of use.

If you would like a more elaborate solution, you can have a look at [smanage](https://github.com/esurface/smanage) and at [atools](https://github.com/gjbex/atools)