# Get which task from slurm job array has failed

Tags: slurm

I have run a slurm job array (9714509) and it failed with a `Mixed, ExitCode [0-1]`. Using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70299897/how-to-get-count-of-failed-and-completed-jobs-in-an-array-job-of-slurm), I can see that only one job failed:

```
$ sacct -n -X -j 9714509 -o state%20 | sort | uniq -c
     25            COMPLETED 
      1               FAILED
```

Is there a way to get which task number has failed, because checking the individual log files will take too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `| uniq -c` part, which is the command that does the counting and replace it with a fileter on `FAILED`. Also add the job id in the output of `sacct`:

```
sacct -n -X -j 9714509 -o state%20,jobid%20 | grep FAILED
```

should output what you need.